# rsync - copy files with same name

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, rsync

I have some different files with the same name and I want to copy all of them to the destination which has a flat structure (no directories, just files), is there any way to append some text onto one of the file names so that both can be copied.

Need to use rsync because there are some files that I need to exclude from the copy.

For example:
    `dir1/file1.txt`
    `dir1/dir2/file1.txt`
both get copied, and in the destination there is:
    `file1.txt`
    `file1.txt.txt`

Answer (score 0):

typically, when I want to do some complex name-mungling, I just write the list of files (with `find dir1 >listfiles`) and fix it with a text editor.

for example, `s/^.*\/([^\/]+)$/cp \0 destination/\1/` converts a file like

```
dir1/file1.txt
dir1/dir2/file1.txt
```

to a script like:

```
cp dir1/file1.txt destination/file1.txt
cp dir1/dir2/file1.txt destination/file1.txt
```

then you could do something like `cut -f 3 <listfiles | sort | uniq -d` to find those with the same destination filename.  then go back to the editor and fix those lines.

After a few minutes you get a full script for exactly the copy you want, without surprises because you can see each command and apply the best fix for each case.

Answer (score 0):

As far as i know there is no default option in rsync to do that. But i guess that since you are copying files with the same name but from different directories, you are using
multiple rsync commands.

So, this gives you two options:

Create folders..

```
rsync -av /home/user1/file1 /media/foo/user1/file1
rsync -av /home/user2/file1 /media/foo/user2/file1
etc..
```

or rename the files with an id

```
rsync -av /home/user1/file1 /media/foo/parent_dir-file1
rsync -av /home/user2file1 /media/foo/parent_dir-file1
etc..
```

If you want to use the second solution you can build a simple script. As you are using rsync i suppose that you know the basics on GNU-Linux, so a simple bash script would be enough!

A basic ID is to get the parent folder name and add it as variable to the path of the `rsync` command. ( it won't always work )

IF you want to be sure of a good id you can for example set a counter and increment like

```
 file1-1
 file1-2
 file1-3
```

But you will loose the track of its absolute path.

All the solutions can work, its up to you to choice the one that feed your needs!